# How can I get a List<String> of the keys from a HashMap<String, String>?

Tags: java, android

I have a `HashMap<String, String> item` and I need to get all of the keys from it in an array so I can do this:

```
for (String s : mapKeys)
{
  Log.d("MyString", s);
}
```

How can I do this? Thanks!

Comment: check out http://developer.android.com/reference/java/util/HashMap.html#keySet()

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
for (String s : item.keySet()) {
  Log.d("MyString", s);
}
```

Answer (score 2):

You need to use [`Map#keySet`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/Map.html#keySet%28%29) method that gives you a `Set` of `keys` in HashMap: -

```
Map<String, String> map = new HashMap<String, String>();

for(String key: map.keySet()) {
    Log.d("MyString", key);
}
```

Answer (score 2):

There is [`keySet`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/util/HashMap.html#keySet%28%29) method in the `Map` interface. To obtain an *array* (as you mention in your question) you could use

```
item.keySet().toArray(new String[item.size()])
```

But you could just as easily iterate over the `keySet` itself,

```
for (String s : item.keySet()) {
    ...
}
```

Answer (score 2):

try:

```
for (String key : myHashMap.keySet()) {
}
```

Answer (score 0):

As mentioned in comment check out http://developer.android.com/reference/java/util/HashMap.html#keySet() which return the `Set` of keys. You can run a for loop over the keys `Set` like following:

```
for (String s : item.keySet()) {
  Log.d("hashmap_keys", s);
}
```